# Sensor Fusion for Sensors with different sampling rates

Tags: architecture, sensors, sensor-fusion

let's say we have 3 sensors that can send data at S1(10Hz), S2(50Hz), S3(1000HZ). Now I want to do some sensor fusion using all the 3 sensors. But since their sampling rates are different, how do we achieve this? Does my control loop run at minimum of the 3 sampling frequencies?

Can somebody point me out to a resource where I can read a bit about these kind of problems?